# Consultar um campo com formato datetime year to second, pedindo para trazer somente registros de hoje?

Tags: mysql, informix, ibm

Gostaria de saber como buscar um registro de data, porém trazer este `dat_entrada` somente com a data atual? Segue a query:

```
select
   a1.cdg_filial Filial,
   a1.cdg_fornecedor Fornecedor,
   a2.dcr_fornecedor NomeFornecedor,
   a1.nmr_docto NotaFiscal,
   a1.dat_entrada DataEntrada,
   a1.val_calculado_bonificacao ValorNF,
   a1.cdg_cfop2 CFOP
   from bdodnfe a1, cadforn a2, cadfil a3
where a1.cdg_cfop2 = 1910 or a1.cdg_cfop2 = 2910
and a1.dat_entrada = today
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma função no MySQL que pega a data atual, você pode usa-lo quando precisar inserir a data atual em um registro ou comparar com a data atual. De acordo com o a sua descrição parecia ser essa sua necessidade, caso não seja melhore sua pergunta editando e dando mais detalhes.

```
select
   a1.cdg_filial Filial,
   a1.cdg_fornecedor Fornecedor,
   a2.dcr_fornecedor NomeFornecedor,
   a1.nmr_docto NotaFiscal,
   a1.dat_entrada DataEntrada,
   a1.val_calculado_bonificacao ValorNF,
   a1.cdg_cfop2 CFOP
   from bdodnfe a1, cadforn a2, cadfil a3
where a1.cdg_cfop2 = 1910 or a1.cdg_cfop2 = 2910
and a1.dat_entrada = CURDATE();
```